What is the maximal safe temperature to ride E-bike with winter battery cover?
I lost the plastic battery cover of my Winora Yucatan X12 Pro. It is facing down, and I do not want to ride with the battery compartment exposed. I was not able to find a battery cover for this model anywhere, cheap or expensive, apart from buying another bicycle of this type. I would attempt to 3D print it, but there is no drawing.
One idea would be to put an external battery cover, closing the exposed compartment this way. External covers, however, are meant for winter riding, to provide thermal insulation battery benefits from in these conditions. I have some fear of my battery overheating in summer or even autumn or spring with such a cover on.
Is there any information on at which highest external temperatures external covers are still acceptable to use?

With the loss of the cover I'd be more concerned about whether it's supposed to keep water and dirt out of there.  That bike is expensive enough that it's worth contacting the manufacturer directly.  Even for cheap e-bikes there are spare parts sold but not listed by dealers (I've bought a few in the past)

Manufacturer responded they will not help.

I don't believe it would overheat that easily.
The maximum wattage of a street-legal e-bike is generally 250 watts. Short term, it can produce more power, but for heat purposes we're interested in the maximum long-term power.
Round trip efficiency of lithium-ion batteries is 95%. If we assume half of the lost energy is due to charging and half due to discharging, the energy loss would be 2.5% when discharging.
So it will heat at a rate of 250 W * 0.025 = 6.25 W. This assuming you require the maximum 250 watt assist all the time. For me, I can go 130 kilometers with 500 watt-hours at 25 km/h, so my average wattage is around 100 W, not 250 W.
That's not much.
Besides, a winter battery cover closes the battery only from one side. The battery presumably sits against a frame tube, which is metal and which can dissipate lots of energy.
Remember also that the maximum safe temperature for a battery is generally 60 degrees Celsius.
What a winter battery cover does, is if it even works, to increase the temperature of the battery maybe 10 degrees Celsius. This means a typical freezing winter temperature of the battery, let's say -5 degrees Celsius, becomes +5 degrees Celsius which already improves the performance of the battery a lot. This assuming the winter cover even works, I'm skeptical that they would have this good performance, since the battery cover doesn't cover the battery from all sides, so major heat leaking pathways are still present.
It's a long way to reach +60 degrees Celsius. You would have to ride close to the equator to be able to reach that kinds of temperatures.
If you don't believe me, buy an infrared thermometer and ride using the winter battery cover, then measure the temperature of the battery with an infrared thermometer. I doubt you would reach high temperatures.

"if it works" - it should probably be lined with insulation to have any chance of doing much, but even then it can do two things: (i) retain heat from being stored/charged somewhere warm; (ii) keep the heat from the battery losses in the battery.  In practice for rides of more than a few minutes, it's both.  You won't get any real benefit if the battery starts from cold, because the self-heating is too small.

Indeed, for retaining heat of a previously warm battery, it could work better.

... and IIRC the worst thing for Li ion batteries in the cold is charging them too cold, so you should be charging indoors anyway
